# Automatic lookup of indexers in the C# debugger, like in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

In VB.NET, if I have this code:

```
Session("something")
```

And I'm in the debugger and mouse over `Session`, I see the value of the session variable using the indexer. However if I write equivalent code in C#:

```
Session["something"]
```

I just see info on the `Session` variable itself. Is there any way to enable the VB style behavior in C#?

Comment: My guess would be that the VB code is actually invoking the default `Item` property and it is that property that VB is showing you, while the C# equivalent has no actual property, so no. That's just speculation though..

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the `Locals` panel.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think the C# code is compiled into an `Item` property behind the scenes.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue you meet. I think it is the problem of design. We can not use code to change it. I suggest that you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: OK, good idea! I have posted a feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1002297/automatic-lookup-of-indexers-in-the-c-debugger-lik.html